# Upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04.1 fails at grub installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, do-release-upgrade

The pop-up window says:

[ ] Writing GRUB to boot devide failed - continue?

The terminal window shows:

Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.142.6+2.04-1ubuntu26.4) ...
Trying to migrate /boot/efi to esp config
Installing grub to /var/lib/grub/esp.
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: /var/lib/grub/esp doesn't look like an EFI partition.

On my system, /var/lib/grub/esp is an empty directory, created on 2020-09-08.

My system is a Lenovo X1 Carbon, with a SSD.  It's dual boot: Windows 10 (came installed with the hardware, but it's almost never used) and Ubuntu.

Can anyone suggest how I should proceed with the update?  Is it safe to proceed (and recover a potentially damaged boot configuration)?

Comment: I got the same thing and it was trying the wrong place during the upgrade, you want to chose your main drive like sda or sdb, not a directory and when I chose sda which is my primary drive all worked as expected.

Comment: How do I change the device in the middle of the upgrade?

Comment: I use terminal while using Something Else or manual install. Partitions do not seem to get mounted in the install until you add password. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 I just did this today with a second install of Kubuntu 20.10, but wanted to use ESP in sdb, so main working install's ESP was not modified.